# Object Notation vs. Curly Bracket Notation

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

Are there any differences in performance or functionality between the following property setting and object declaration in JavaScript?

```
var a = {
  b: 'A property',
  c: 1
};
```

vs.

```
var a = {};
a.b = 'A property';
a.c = 1;
```

And, if I were to clear all properties of an object, which of the following would be better and why?

```
var a = {};
```

vs.

```
a.b = undefined;
a.c = undefined;
```

Thank you!

Comment: With regard to the performance related questions - https://jsperf.com/ is a great tool for testing JS performance in browser.

Comment: In what universe would this be the bottleneck in your application?

Comment: He's asking for *“performance **or** functionality ”*. «What universe» is completely irrelevant. Sometimes the ignorant superiority complex of “know it all's” irritates me on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Object declaration / expanding it

- Curly bracket notation is an object literal declaration.
- Simply curly brackets with no properties is like `Object.create(null)`: an empty object whose prototype is `Object`.

## About dropping properties.

- Setting other empty object (i.e. `{}`) to a variable which holds a reference to an object is just reusing the same reference and make it point to a new object.
- Setting an existing object properties to `undefined` doesn't equal to *remove the properties*. You're just setting `undefined` as their values, since in JavaScript `undefined` is a possible value.

In order to drop properties you need to use `delete` sentence:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(propertyName) {
    // This really deletes the property from the object
    delete obj[propertyName];
});
```

Comment: `Object.create(null)` doesn't have prototype.

Comment: What do you mean by *«Simply curly brackets with no properties is like `Object.create(null)`»* ? I.e. try this: `a = {}; b = Object.create(null);` Here `b` will have *nothing* whilst `a` has all the proto properties. (I.e. `__proto__, constructor, toString, ...`)

Answer (score 1):

for clearing properties it's probably better to do `var a = {}` because then you aren't making assumptions about what properties are set.  You're guaranteed an empty object even if some other properties have been added to `a`.

For setting properties, it doesn't matter as much.  If the object properties are set once and then not changed, then assigning the object with all its properties in one operation more clearly indicates your intent.

Answer (score 1):

**Declaration:**
I see no functional difference. For a performance statement I would need to do measurements which are likely to be engine specific. I would expect no difference, but that is just guesswork, thus measure.

**Clearing:**
You are doing two different things here:

- `a = {};` replaces the value for `a` with an empty object, having no
  properties (except the default ones)
- `a.property = undefined;` replaces the value of the property with
  `undefined`, keeping the properties but marking them as not set with
  a proper value.

That seems like a matter of taste, depending on the
   sitation and if other code depends on the properties existing.